# Using CSS Variables to allow us to shorten code in angular

Tags: css, angular, generics, angular-material

We have been struggling with a lot of code duplication in terms of css while using material tables in our project. Defining each column with set widths (for readability)
eg:

```css
        .mat-table {
            bottom: 56px;

            mat-column {
                align-items: center;
            }

            .mat-column-col1 {
                min-width: 80px;
            }

            .mat-column-col2 {
                min-width: 100px;
            }

            .mat-column-col3 {
                min-width: 150px;
            }

            .mat-column-col4 {
                min-width: 100px;
            }
}
```

We recently build a a component to handle building a table for us but sat with the problem that we would have to define a lot of custom css to build this in our style

```html
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns; let i = index">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ col }}" [sticky]="tableConfig[i].sticky">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header="{{ col }}">
                        {{ tableConfig[i].display }}
                    </th>
                    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="tableConfig[i].type">
                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[col] }}</td>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'date'">
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[col] | date : "yyyy/MM/dd" }}</td>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'dateAndTime'">
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[col] | date : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" : tableConfig[i].timeZone }}</td>
                        </div>
```

This is more or less how we build up the html and then the typescript does some conversion to get everything in the correct format.

How would we cleanup the css ?

Answer (score 1):

We struggled finding many useful links on css parameterisation but then finally cleaned it up an insane amount

```html
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header="{{ col }}" class="col-width" style="--width: {{ tableConfig[i].width }}">
```

Looking at the header definition firstly you need to define a class that will use the variable (in our case "col-width") and then add a style param in the mix `style="--width: {{ tableConfig[i].width }}"`, we have a whole ts side that builds a big array with the relevant info for a column.

Then in the css you can define it to use variables

```css
.col-width {
    min-width: var(--width);
}
```

And now we can just add all the variables we need, this keeps our typescript about the same complexity but our HTML and CSS are super basic